# Spring-Oauth2 Access Token request never succeeds due to missing CSRF 'preserved state'

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I've been working the last couple days to get an implementation of spring boot / spring security / and java configuration working with spring-security-oauth2. I've managed to work through most of the difficulties, but am stumped as to what is going wrong now.

I am completing the following steps successfully:

- sending user to the provider to authorize the application to act on their behalf
- user is prompted to sign in to provider per security
- user authorizes the app, and the redirect url sends them back to the client app at the original url along with `?code=asdfa&state=asdfasf`in the query string

At this point, I believe whatever is using the `AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails` should be exchanging the authorization code and client app credentials for an access token. This is where the process is failing with the following stack trace.

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.InvalidRequestException: Possible CSRF detected - state parameter was present but no state could be found
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.getParametersForTokenRequest(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:246)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:198)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainNewAccessTokenInternal(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:142)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.createRequest(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:564)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:529)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:261)
    at com.pvr.apps.admin.user.UserServiceImpl.getAllUsers(UserServiceImpl.java:51)
    at com.pvr.apps.admin.web.IndexController.serveUserList(IndexController.java:35)
```

Things on the client look like (I also have an `@EnableOAuth2Client` annotation on the main config).

```
@Component
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Resource
    @Qualifier("accessTokenRequest")
    private AccessTokenRequest accessTokenRequest;

    public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails createResource() {
        AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails resourceDetails = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
        resourceDetails.setScope(Lists.newArrayList("read", "write"));
        resourceDetails.setClientId("admin");
        resourceDetails.setClientSecret("password");
        resourceDetails.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.query);
        resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("http://provider.com:8080/oauth/token");
        resourceDetails.setUserAuthorizationUri("http://provider.com:8080/oauth/authorize");
        return resourceDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {

        RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(createResource(), new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(accessTokenRequest));

        ResponseEntity<User[]> responseEntity = template.getForEntity("http://provider.com:8080/users/", User[].class);
        return Lists.newArrayList(responseEntity.getBody());
    }
}
```

And on the provider side of things:

The authorization server config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .tokenKeyAccess("isAnonymous() || hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')")
                .checkTokenAccess("hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();

        endpoints
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .accessTokenConverter(converter)
                .tokenStore(new JwtTokenStore(converter));
    }


    // TODO: this should read from a db
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clientConfigurer) throws Exception {
        clientConfigurer.inMemory()
                .withClient("admin").secret("password")
                .authorizedGrantTypes(
                        GrantType.PASSWORD.type,
                        GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE.type,
                        GrantType.IMPLICIT.type,
                        GrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN.type
                )
                .authorities("ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60);
    }
}
```

and the resource server config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailService;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login.do")
                    .usernameParameter("uid")
                    .passwordParameter("pwd")
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .and()
                .userDetailsService(userDetailService);
    }

}
```

Comment: Also, I'm planning on doing a write-up around all of this once I understand it. Current documentation and examples are sparse and a bit jumbled between older workarounds and newer conveniences. @Rob Winch?

Comment: I am also having the same error but I am implementing OAuth2 using three apps Authorize, resource and client server all are running on different ports it is ending up on the same URL as yours.

Comment: Hi @Paul_R can you share the code for the auth you have written ? Your code structure is very different from other example i have stumbled upon, it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The state it is looking for would be in the `OAuth2ClientContext` but since you have just created a new one it is out of scope when it is needed. If you inject the one that comes from `@EnableOAuth2Client` instead it will be in `@Scope("session")` so it will be able to resolve the state for you. All the samples in GitHub work that way. Or you can manage the persistence yourself, I guess.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that makes sense. Unfortunately, the server is now providing `OAuth2AccessDeniedException: Invalid token for client`. when trying to fetch the resource. I've confirmed that the access token IS in the header sent. Can you see anything else that looks off or provide some direction?

Comment: Removed the jwt token configuration and now getting a `UserDeniedAuthorizationException`.. does that mean that the provider is not remembering the authorization?

Comment: Your "resource server" isn't actually an OAuth2 resource server (no `@EnableResourceServer`). Maybe you pasted the wrong code? Is `UserDeniedAuthorizationException` on the auth server (seems like an obvious hint).

Comment: Ah, we figured it out. We had to explicitly set .approvalStoreDisabled() on the EndpointsConfigurer since we weren't approving by scope. The logic in AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer#userApprovalHandler is a bit unclear as we were expecting a TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler to be created to wrap our token store, but in reality it was creating a ApprovalStoreUserApprovalHandler.

Comment: @Dave Syer - I am also having this same problem but configurations files are slight different as I am having 3 apps for handling this stuff. here is my question I asked [here is the link for question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160210/not-able-to-access-oauth-access-token)